# Javascript is causing MASSIVE memory leaks

Tags: javascript, loops, memory-management, memory-leaks, infinite-loop

Our home PC has come to a halt all of a sudden unexpectedly numerous times in the past couple days. It takes the UI about half an hour to recover, and sometime a hard reboot is needed. Opening Task Manager reveals that one particular PID is using about 96% of the PC's RAM, and using Chrome Task Manager, I have determined it to be a webpage I made.

I don't know much about memory leaks, as I've only heard of them in passing, but I am almost certain that my Javascript code has somehow caused a memory leak. Is there a best practice to modify code to stop memory leaks? I suspect the leak is being caused by my `response()` function.

Before this question is downvoted for being a duplicate or providing no research, [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461274/why-is-this-delayed-while-loop-causing-a-massive-memory-leak) has led me to believe that `case "12124561414":` could be the culprit; however, I have not been able to test this. Furthermore, the loop contains within this function is not executing, so I am uncertain of whether or not that is truly the culprit, since I am not aware of any built-in JS mechanisms to isolate memory leaks.

Is there any way to run indefinite loops without causing memory leaks? (if that is indeed why I am experiencing huge memory leaks) Or some way to release these resources that are apparently *not* being released? My goal is to have the busy tone just run over and over again for eternity until the page is refreshed, but I see no reason that should crash the computer.

The complete JS code for this webpage is below:

```
    var availableNumbers = ["0", "911", "1 (847) 765-1008" , "867-5309", "1 (212) 456-1414", "555-1212", "555-5555"];
    function numberSuggestion() {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (availableNumbers.length));
        var suggestedNumber = availableNumbers[randomNumber];
        document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = "How about dialing <strong id='suggestedTelephoneNumber'>" + suggestedNumber + "</strong>? Don't like this number? Click the button above again!";
    }
    var dialTone;
    function offHook() {
        document.getElementById("WE2500").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("dialPad").style.display = "block";
        dialTone = new Audio('dialTone.m4a');
        dialTone.play();
    }
    var number = "";
    var timeout;
    function numberDial() {
        if (dialTone) {
            dialTone.pause();
            dialTone.currentTime = 0;
        }
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(dial, 2000);
    }
    function dial1() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "1";
        var tone1 = new Audio('DTMF-1.wav');
        tone1.play();
    }
    function dial2() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "2";
        var tone2 = new Audio('DTMF-2.wav');
        tone2.play();
    }
    function dial3() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "3";
        var tone3 = new Audio('DTMF-3.wav');
        tone3.play();
    }
    function dial4() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "4";
        var tone4 = new Audio('DTMF-5.wav');
        tone4.play();
    }
    function dial5() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "5";
        var tone5 = new Audio('DTMF-5.wav');
        tone5.play();
    }
    function dial6() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "6";
        var tone6 = new Audio('DTMF-6.wav');
        tone6.play();
    }
    function dial7() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "7";
        var tone7 = new Audio('DTMF-7.wav');
        tone7.play();
    }
    function dial8() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "8";
        var tone8 = new Audio('DTMF-8.wav');
        tone8.play();
    }
    function dial9() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "9";
        var tone9 = new Audio('DTMF-9.wav');
        tone9.play();
    }
    function dial0() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "0";
        var tone0 = new Audio('DTMF-0.wav');
        tone0.play();
    }
    function dialStar() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "*";
        var toneStar = new Audio('DTMF-star.wav');
        toneStar.play();
    }
    function dialPound() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "#";
        var tonePound = new Audio('DTMF-pound.wav');
        tonePound.play();
    }
    var ringingTone = new Audio('DTMF-ringbackTone.mp3');
    var timesRung = 0;
    function dial() {
        function ring() {
            ringingTone.play();
            timesRung++;
            if (timesRung > 1) {
                setTimeout(response, 700);
            }
        }
        ring();
        setTimeout(ring, 4000);
    }
    function response() {
        switch(number) {
            case "0":
                var operatorPickup = new Audio('OperatorAnswer.wav');
                operatorPickup.addEventListener("ended", function(){
                    number = prompt("Operator, your number please? (Numbers only; enter 'police' for police and emergency)");
                    if (number == null) {
                        number = "0";
                    }
                    operatorPutCallThrough();
                });
                operatorPickup.play();
                break;
            case "911":
                var pickup911 = new Audio('911-xxx-fleet.mp3');
                pickup911.play();
                break;
            case "18477651008":
                var pickupMCI = new Audio('MCI.wav');
                pickupMCI.play();
                break;
            case "8675309":
                var pickup8675309 = new Audio('discoornis-bell-f1.mp3');
                pickup8675309.play();
                break;
            case "12124561414":
                var pickupBusy = new Audio('tele-busy.wav');
                console.log(number);
                while (number == "12124561414") {
                    pickupBusy.play();
                    pickupBusy.currentTime = 0;
                }
                break;
            case "5551212":
                var pickupLocalInfo = new Audio('tele-busy.wav');
                pickupLocalInfo.play();
                break;
            case "5555555":
                var pickup5555555 = new Audio('timeout-bell-f1.mp3');
                pickup5555555.play();
                break;
            case "police":
                break;
            default:
                var pickupDefault = new Audio('ldcircuits-bell-f1.mp3');
                pickupDefault.play();
        }
    }
    function operatorPutCallThrough() {
        alert("One moment please, ringing the line now.");
        if (number == "police") {
            var operatorPoliceTransfer = new Audio('OperatorPolice.wav');
            operatorPoliceTransfer.play();
        }
        response();
    }
```

My hunch is this might be a better approach, but I'm a little scared to test it in case the PC crashes again.

```
            case "12124561414":
                busy();
                break;
            case "5551212":
                busy();
                break;
            case "5555555":
                var pickup5555555 = new Audio('timeout-bell-f1.mp3');
                pickup5555555.play();
                break;
            case "police":
                break;
            default:
                var pickupDefault = new Audio('ldcircuits-bell-f1.mp3');
                pickupDefault.play();
        }
    }
    function busy() {
        function() busyTone {
            var pickupBusy = new Audio('tele-busy.wav');
            pickupBusy.play();
            pickupBusy.currentTime = 0;
        }
        setInterval(function() busyTone, 1);
    }
```

Comment: Does your program start to slow down at a given part of its run? For example, `case "12124561414":`, I see a while loop in there with a condition set that doesn't seem to be changing, so possible infinite loop? I'm not exactly sure how to test your code, but maybe getting a better idea of the root cause will help here

Comment: We have a relatively slow computer, but it will just run fine until all of a sudden, the UI becomes inanimate and the nonresponsive. If you press CTRL+SHIFT+ESC, after about 15 minutes, a taskmgr comes up and I can check out what's going on. The problem is, I need an infinite loop there but without the memory problems.

Comment: Because you don't signify any particular moment for the crash, I suggest it happens before any numbers are entered? Each case in the switch statements is a particular case which does not execute until the case happens. If this is true, there is a problem before the numbers are entered.

Comment: In the function called dial, aren't you continuously calling the function ring   (`setTimeout(ring, 4000)`) which **continously** does a setTimeout to make a call to the function response ( `if (timesRung > 1) setTimeout(response, 700);` )? I think timesRung is always > 1?

Comment: @MPS Actually, it only happens sometimes - if a certain number is dialed, that is correct. No, the times Rung function is fine. It rings twice. If timesRung is great than 1, that loop stops. So we're all good there, it took lots of tweaking to get that right

Comment: @MPS Will adding this function in the response() function help? if (timesRung > 1) {
    ringingTone.pause();
    ringingTone.currentTime = 0;
   }

Comment: @ Interlinked: the dial function does not seem to be the problem. But I am curious, you said if a certain number is dialed ... do you mean it is the same number each time? If so, that would of course be valuable info.

Comment: @MPS I posted the whole function, you can take a look - the number that is dialed is based on user input. I just had to have that there so your hear it ringing twice before the call is "answered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most significantly, it seems you're confused about infinite loops. Some browsers *will* hang when you enter one. For example, enter this into your JS console, and you might see a hang similar to yours:

```
var number = "12124561414";
while (number == "12124561414") { /* do nothing */ }
```

The issue here is that the `while` loop runs in the same thread as the GUI loop, and so the GUI will lock up until that loop halts.

A solution to this problem presents itself in a similar form to other pieces of code you've provided here. For example, this code plays a tone once after some period of time, allowing the GUI to update between that period of time:

```
function numberDial() {
    if (dialTone) {
        dialTone.pause();
        dialTone.currentTime = 0;
    }
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(dial, 2000);
}
```

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead, and you'll have `dial` invoked every 2 seconds until you use `clearInterval` to stop it, allowing the GUI loop to continue its job (refreshing the user interface) until that two seconds has passed.

---

To answer your questions:

> Is there a best practice to modify code to stop memory leaks?

Put heavy critical thought into designing your software so that objects don't hang around unnecessarily.

> Is there any way to run indefinite loops without causing memory leaks?

I think a [Rust doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/leaking.html) answers this nicely...

> ... It's quite trivial to initialize a collection at the start of a program, fill it with tons of objects with destructors, and then enter an infinite event loop that never refers to it. The collection will sit around uselessly, holding on to its precious resources until the program terminates (at which point all those resources would have been reclaimed by the OS anyway).

In other words, *it depends upon the loop, and what occurred **before** the loop*!

Let us consider what's happening in this line of code *immediately before* your (browser-hanging) loop: `console.log(number);`. I believe *this* to be the *only possible leak* in the code you've identified, as this causes a reference to `number`, as an object, to be stored into such a collection (the *debug* logs).

As it turns out from further analysis, this probably *isn't* a leak, as `number` is declared outside of the function anyway... It's worthwhile to note, however, that `console.log` *can prevent an object from being considered garbage*!

> Or some way to release these resources that are apparently *not* being released?

I suggest ensuring that the garbage collector can do its job to reclaim those resources by logging conditionally to reduce the amount that gets stored. As it is, the reference you're pushing onto the logs will also store other references (back to the global object, for example).

Comment: That `while` loop is definitely a problem, but normally I'd expect that to lock up just the browser, not the whole computer.

Comment: That's likely a sign that your computer is out of memory, and so when task switching occurs the memory occupied by the process is commonly swapped to hard disk to make room for the next task's scheduled execution. Your OS then swaps that memory back to RAM later when the browser gets execution time again. As you can imagine this process is quite intensive. If this switching involves too many open tabs (not just that *one*, but also any that are currently open or *able to be reopened* (you know *that leaky feature*?)), this is likely to exacerbate the issue *dramatically*!

Comment: Thanks all, I only had a couple tabs open because this PC only has 2 or 3 GB of RAM and it isn't mine, so there are 91 programs installed, most of them junkware, that run their own junk processes all the time I have to put up. I have a logon script that terminates as many of them as possible but only so much can be done... I was using console.log() because the code beneath it was not working - that was purely debugging. That will not be part of the actual program when it's finished.

Comment: So, the recording I have of busy tone (the busy signal) is 3 seconds long. If I open it in WMP with repeat turned on, the busy signal sounds continuous with no interruptions. Does that mean my setInterval would have to be 0 or 1?

Comment: Is there a way to analyze/debug code for memory leaks? Maybe an online validator? MPS thinks timesRung could be causing a leak but I'm not sure how...

Comment: Got busy tone to work fine and fixed the leaks, thanks all!